# Is this Facebook layout legitimate or a scam?

Tags: facebook, google-chrome

I've been having some trouble loading Facebook on Chrome. At first my wall simply didn't load and many of the options were not working properly. A few moments later a trojan was found in my computer after a quick MalwareBytes scan and I've been wondering whether it was possible that I was not really on Facebook but some kind of trap site to get passwords.

This is the current layout that only shows up in Chrome. I've tried loading Facebook with several other browsers and devices and they are still displaying the "older" layout. Even Chrome Incognito mode is showing a different layout. Is it possible that this is a scam? If so, what do I have to do to remove it?

[image]

**Edit:**
I tried deactivating Chrome extensions one by one but none of them seems to be the cause for this.

Comment: Did you check the URL in the address bar ?

Answer (score 2):

Chances are they were running an A/B test of a new design,  or were pushing new code.  Facebook software release includes pushing new code to a small portion of its users to verify it's functioning as designed. You most likely had a cookie allowing you to see the new design,  and it was on that specific browser.  Reinstalling Chrome changed your cookies,  and wasn't selected that time.

In a week or so,  you will see it on all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

First change your Facebook password. NOW!

You can't judge from the layout of a website if it's a phishing website or not. If your computer still is infected, they could just use a keylogger to get your login credentials.

Run another scan with MalwareBytes Anti-Malware and then Windows Essentials to make sure the threat is really gone. Then install anti-virus and keep things updated. I also highly suggest changing your passwords to other services.

Comment: I changed the password and added increased security with mobile confirmation. I'm not sure how to fix the problem though. I'll try running a few more scans to see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

This might sound a bit too tech support but uninstalling and reinstalling worked. Facebook now loads the standard layout and I'm not having any trouble loading anything on it.

I still have no idea what caused it. Oh well.

Comment: What did you uninstall?

Comment: @axrwkr Google Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, don't go by the looks of the page. Though that may be the first indication that something is wrong, always observe the URI/URL in your browser. Go to https://www.facebook.com [Always safer to use HTTPS]

Rely on your browser's indication to show you if the secure HTTPS link is correct (Green / lock symbol). If that seems fine, go ahead and log in. You can also try going to https://www.facebook.com/[YOUR FACEBOOK USERNAME] and log in. Facebook allows you to log in and view any page that you were trying to access. If you get redirected from a particular Facebook page when you were trying to log in, be cautious (unless you entered your credentials incorrectly). If you think you Facebook account may be compromised, its always better to change your password anyway.

Additional Tip: Try using another browser (For Example: Firefox) to compare page display

Comment: Funny thing is the url was correct and it was using HTTPS. I opened the main FB page on several browsers like I described and only Chrome was showing this unusual main page.

Comment: If you think your browser was compromised, try backing up your favorites and bookmarks and re-installing chrome. You can search, find and run several malware and spyware programs that will remove hidden harmful components. Try again after that!

Answer (score 0):

I would try resetting your computer and clearing out all your browser's cache files and then doing an actual restart.  When the computer comes back online load chrome and hold down the shift key when you load www.facebook.com and see if that does the trick.  Good luck fixing it It's most likely a cache error that needs to be cleaned.